# Windows equivalent of /dev/random

Tags: windows, random

Is there a way to generate random number on Windows by reading from a file or pseudo file or character special file, the way that can be done on Linux by reading from [/dev/random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urandom#Linux)? Not asking about various crypto API, but whether there is in Windows something akin to the Linux way.

Comment: I wish someone had actually answered the question that was asked. There are plenty of answers to the generic question *how can I generate random numbers on Windows*, but that is not this question. This question specifically asks about `/dev/random` which is a way to generate random numbers by reading from a “file”. This is much more interesting than just generating random numbers by calling a function. **This** is what I want to know. For the record, it’s not exactly the same, but [there are solutions for Windows and DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Other_operating_systems).

Comment: The question is on-topic and not a question for "a tool, library or favorite off-site resource".

Comment: This PERFECTLY VALID question is super useful, and NOT a "recommendation of a tool". Another example of the dark side of S.O.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's called [Microsoft CryptoAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)#Windows).

Answer (score 1):

This link from StingyJack's answer is good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom

Microsoft C++ Visual Studio since 2005 offers [`rand_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8.aspx) which works on Windows XP and up.  It is based on [`RtlGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387694.aspx) (as are CryptoAPI's PRNG functions), whose inner workings are not made public. It seems in XP there were some weaknesses that have since been fixed.

Personally, I use `rand_s()` as an additional source of randomness to seed a PRNG of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing .NET development you can use the [RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) class.