# Is user delay between random takes is good improvement for PRNG?

Tags: algorithm, entropy, prng

I thought that for making random choices for example for next track in a player or next page in the browser it could be possible to use time as 'natural phenomenon', for example decent RPNG just can continuously get next random number without program request (for example in a thread every several milliseconds or event more often) and when the time comes (based on the user decision), the choice will be naturally affected by this user delay.

Is this approach is good enough and how can it be tested? The problem for testing manually is that I can not wait that long in real world to save enough random numbers to feed them to some test program. Any artificial attempt to speed this up will make the method itself invalid.

Thanks

Comment: You might find this useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random It uses the same concept, but takes it a bit further.

Comment: biziclop, thanks for pointing out, recently I also discovered this, nice concept, but unavailable on Windows

Comment: For Windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191335/windows-equivalent-of-dev-random

Answer (score 2):

A good random number generator really doesn't need improvement, and even if it did, it isn't clear that user input timing would help.

Could a user ever detect a pattern in tracks selected by an LCG? Whatever your platform, its likely that its built-in `random()` function would be good enough (that is, it would appear *completely* random to a user).

If you are still worried, however, use a cryptographic quality RNG, seeded with data from the dedicated source of randomness on your system. Nowadays, many of these system RNGs use truly random bits generated through quantum events in hardware. However, they can be slow to produce bits, so its best to use them as a seed for a fast, algorithmic PRNG.

Now, if you aren't convinced these approaches are good enough, you should be very skeptical that the timing of user typing is a good source. The keys that are pressed by users are *highly* predictable, given the limited vocabulary in use and the patterns that tend to appear within that limited set of words. This predictability in letter sequences leads to a high degree of predictability in timing between key presses.

I know that a lot of security programs use this technique during key generation. I don't think that it is pure snake oil, but it could be a placebo to placate users. A good product will depend on the system RNG.

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring the time information that you describe can indeed add entropy to a PRNG. However, from your description of your intended applications, I don't think you need it. For "random choices for example for next track in a player or next page in the browser", a trivial, unmodified PRNG is fine. For security applications such as nonces, etc. it is much more important.

Anyway, you should read about PRNG entropy sources.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't improve PRNGs with user delays, mostly because they're quite regular: you type at around the same speed, and it takes too long to measure the delay between a click and another (assuming normal usage). I'd rather use other user-triggered events: pressed keys, distance between each click, position of the mouse at given moments.